# Как добавить жирный шрифт для введеных символов в AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Как сделать чтобы текст выделялся жирным шрифтом как показано на картинке в AutoCompleteTextView?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в адаптере используйте spannable